# Synchronization doesn't work for the given code example

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

In the following code, I am trying to print the thread name and the hash code value of the `vector` object but the output is not as expected. Also, the singleton is broken since hash code values are not consistent for the `vector` object.

```
public class ThreadTestVector implements Runnable {

private static Vector<String> vector;

public static synchronized Vector<String> getInstance() {
    if (vector == null) {
        vector = new Vector<String>();
    }
    return vector;
}

@Override
public synchronized void run() {

    Vector<String> vector = getInstance();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        vector.add(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(vector.get(i) + " Hash Code "
                + vector.hashCode());
    }
    // clear the vector for values already printed
    vector.clear();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Runnable r = new ThreadTestVector();
    Runnable r1 = new ThreadTestVector();
    Runnable r2 = new ThreadTestVector();
    Runnable r3 = new ThreadTestVector();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(r);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(r1);
    Thread t3 = new Thread(r2);
    Thread t4 = new Thread(r3);
    t1.start();
    // Thread.sleep(100);
    t2.start();
    // Thread.sleep(100);
    t3.start();
    // Thread.sleep(100);
    t4.start();

}

}
```

On execution following output pattern is produced
Thread-0 Hash Code 924221025
Thread-0 Hash Code 1030242113
Thread-0 Hash Code 1030242113
Thread-0 Hash Code 1030242113
Thread-0 Hash Code -119973247
Thread-0 Hash Code 1030242113
Thread-0 Hash Code 1030242113
Thread-0 Hash Code 1030242113
Thread-0 Hash Code 1030242113
Thread-0 Hash Code 1030242113
Thread-0 Hash Code 1030242113
Thread-0 Hash Code 1030242113
Thread-0 Hash Code 1030242113
Thread-0 Hash Code 1030242113
Thread-1 Hash Code 1030242113
Thread-1 Hash Code 1030242113
Thread-1 Hash Code 1030242113
Thread-1 Hash Code 1030242113
Thread-1 Hash Code 1030242113
Thread-1 Hash Code 1030242113
Thread-1 Hash Code 1030242113
Thread-1 Hash Code 1030242113
Thread-1 Hash Code 1030242113
Thread-1 Hash Code 1030242113
Thread-2 Hash Code 1030242113
Thread-2 Hash Code 1030242113
Thread-2 Hash Code 1030242113
Thread-2 Hash Code 1030242113
Thread-2 Hash Code 1030242113
Thread-2 Hash Code 1030242113
Thread-2 Hash Code 1030242113
Thread-2 Hash Code 1030242113
Thread-2 Hash Code 1030242113
Thread-2 Hash Code 1030242113
Thread-3 Hash Code 1030242113
Thread-3 Hash Code 1030242113
Thread-3 Hash Code 1030242113
Thread-3 Hash Code 1030242113
Thread-3 Hash Code 1030242113
Thread-3 Hash Code 1030242113
Thread-3 Hash Code 1030242113
Thread-3 Hash Code 1030242113
Thread-3 Hash Code 1030242113
Thread-3 Hash Code 1030242113
Thread-0 Hash Code 1901327073
Thread-0 Hash Code 1030242113
Thread-0 Hash Code 1030242113

Which is all jumbled up and hash code values are also different.

How to fix it so that output is printed in a synchronized manner and hash code values are consistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should synchronize vector

```
if (vector != null) {
 synchronized(vector) {
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        vector.add(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(vector.get(i) + " Hash Code "
                + vector.hashCode());
    }
    // clear the vector for values already printed
    vector.clear();
}
}
```

Comment: thanks! It does fix the problem. Could you please explain why synchronizing the run method was not helping?

Comment: you should synchronize the Object which will be accessed by different thread simultaneously. Otherwise, you can not protect it

Answer (score 1):

Hash code values are different because a Vector's hash code is computed from its contents.

So it is not surprising you're getting differents values for your hashcode.